# Same code works perfectly with other API but not with certain API in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get quotes from the following API but app freezes when I hit the API call. I have tried to call the other API using same function, it works properly, but when I tried with this API, it suddenly stops functioning and app freezes.
This is the API:

```
class APPURL {
  static String baseURL = 'https://api.quotable.io/';
  String quoteURL = '${baseURL}quotes?limit=10';
  static String quoteBaseURL = "https://dummyjson.com";
  String quoteEndPointURL = "$quoteBaseURL/quotes?";
}
```

Here is my code:

```
 Future<dynamic> getQuoteAPI(int limit, int skip) async {
            try {
              final data = await _networkApi.GETRequest(APPURL.quoteBaseURL);
              print("data");
              print(data.toString());
              return data;
            }
             catch (e) {
              rethrow;
            }
          }  Future<dynamic> GETRequest(String url) async {
            dynamic responseData;
            try {
              Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
              http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
              responseData = await returnJson(response);
              print("response data$responseData");
            } on SocketException {
              throw FetchDataException("No internet connection");
            } on TimeoutException {
              throw FetchDataException("Timeout for network connection");
            } catch (e) {
              print("catch");
              print(e.toString());
              throw FetchDataException("Error during API call: $e");
            }
            return responseData;
          }
Future<dynamic> returnJson(http.Response response) async {
    final data = response.body;
    print("data$data");
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        dynamic decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
        if (decodedData is List) {
          return decodedData;
        } else {
          return [decodedData];
        }
      case 400:
        throw UnAuthorizedRequest(data);
      case 404:
        throw BadRequestException(data);
      case 500:
        throw InternalServerError(data);
      default:
        throw FetchDataException(data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL for `getQuoteAPI()` seems like incorrect.

Try to modify the `quoteEndPointURL` modifier to `static` and then
 replace `final data = await _networkApi.GETRequest(APPURL.quoteBaseURL);` 
with `final data = await _networkApi.GETRequest(APPURL.quoteEndPointURL);`